# How to change permission with omniauth facebook and koala

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook, omniauth

I am using the following gems: omniauth_facebook and koala

When a user logs in they grant the app basic facebook rights

```
current_user.facebook.get_connection("me", "permissions")

{"installed"=>1, "basic_info"=>1, "email"=>1, "user_friends"=>1}
```

I want them to click a button that grants the app `publish_stream` rights. How do I change the scope or permission rights of current user?

Answer (score 1):

Try this, it will work, add into your settings.

> config.omniauth :facebook, ENV['FACEBOOK_KEY'],
>   ENV['FACEBOOK_SECRET'],{:scope => 'publish_stream',
>   :client_options => { :ssl => { :ca_file =>
>   "#{Rails.root}/config/ca-bundle.crt" } } }